# Issue on creating a MAMP virtualhost

Tags: apache, laravel-5, localhost, mamp, virtualhost

I'm trying to create a MAMP virtualhost so that I can use my laravel project easier, but whatever I do I get **" Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server "** when entering localhost or my vh name (cms.dev)

I tried this : [How to create virtual hosts in MAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251032/how-to-create-virtual-hosts-in-mamp)
And this : http://eppz.eu/blog/virtual-host-for-mamp-on-osx/

Even reinstalled MAMP and I still have the same issue, I did everything the same way it's shown in these articles.

Here's my httpd-vhosts.conf config :

```
   #
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Desktop/MAMP"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Desktop/MAMP/cms/public"
    ServerName cms.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you guys know what's happening ???

Thanks

Comment: Are your `DocumentRoot` paths correct?

Comment: Well, that's actually the folder of my projects so I guess it's okay

Comment: Really? In your MacOS you have a `Desktop` folder right under `/`? That seems strange.. are you sure it shouldn't be `/Users/youruser/Desktop/...`? If so, in principle the apps should be in the `Applications` folder...

Comment: Actually before I edit the this line the path was /Application/MAMP..... so guess Desktop is at the same level than Application, am I wrong ?

Comment: You are wrong. Applications is right under /, but the Desktop is under you user folder: `/Users/[yourusername]/Desktop`

Comment: I guess it might be the issue, I'll try later and let you know, thanks !

Comment: Just tried it, and this actually works ! My path was wrong, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DocumentRoot` paths are wrong. In MacOS, the Desktop folder is in `/Users/[yourusername]/Desktop`.