# How to configure multiple virtual hosts for MAMP Free version

Tags: mamp, virtualhost

I've followed several articles about how to configure virtual hosts on Mac using MAMP ([such as this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251032/how-to-create-virtual-hosts-in-mamp)) which involve editing three files:

1. `/etc/hosts`
2. `Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`
3. `Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

That all works fine for one host at a time, but if I configure a second local site (such as mysite.loc), the second site doesn't work: it redirects to which ever one I've pointed the directory to in MAMP free. I know that in XAMPP it would be fine to have several different virtual hosts, but shouldn't this also work with MAMP free? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change the port number for all the virtual hosts in the httpd-vhosts.conf file to the one your apache server is currently using. so those virtual hosts can start utilizing the directories you specified, instead of using the default one that can only be changed in the app.