# How to run simultaneously two local development projects in MAMP

Tags: mamp

I want to inform about this topic. I am working on a project and for testing I need to run the same project twice with different SESSIONs locally. I am using MAMP and doing great!! How can I achieve this? Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

I found the way of achieving this propose it in another way. So I decided to link the post that answers this question if anyone coming to this post could get solution :D [How to create virtual hosts in MAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251032/how-to-create-virtual-hosts-in-mamp)