# Defining Custom URL in MacBook for laravel

Tags: laravel, macos, virtualhost

I just migrated from a windows based laptop to a macbook.
I'm pretty new to MacOS

I'm developing a laravel project in my mac and I want to access the url through custom domain using virtual host such as mylaravel.com or something else, i'm not using xampp, only php, and composer.

for example:
currently I access my laravel project through:

> sudo php artisan serve --port=80

and this is the url to access my

> localhost

what I want is the following url:

> mylaravel.id

How can I achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create virtual hosts in MAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251032/how-to-create-virtual-hosts-in-mamp)

Comment: I'm not using MAMP, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use laravel valet.
look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet) documentation.

Comment: This is very helping. Thank you very much